# ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse

Tags: python, mysql, database, django

I am trying to connecting MySQL database to Django. I have seen many forms but I am unable to solve my problem. Below is what I get when I do `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 429, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 252, in fetch_command
app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 101, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 276, in __getattr__
self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 139, in __init__
logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
  ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'require_debug_false': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse': No module named RequireDebugFalse
```

I am using a virtualenv on Ubuntu.

Logging Information ::

```
   LOGGING = {
   'version': 1,
   'disable_existing_loggers': False,
   'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': True,
    },
}
```

}

Comment: What does your `LOGGING` configuration look like?

Comment: what version of django are you running?

Comment: DATABASES = {
           'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
           'NAME': 'cherrylogin',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
           'USER': 'root',
          'PASSWORD': 'password',
          'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
          'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

Comment: is there a difference in Django versions between your local development and the virtualenv?

Comment: I have not installed django in my local development, I only hav it in my virtual env. Django version: 1.4, python version: 2.7.3, mysql version 14.14

Comment: I'd check your `LOGGING` and make sure you really are using 1.4 since the error indicates your install is missing the `RequireDebugFalse` filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse

Comment: Seems to me that your using a venv that is using a different django version than  the app your trying to run.

Answer (score 6):

From the traceback it is clear you are *not* using a Django version installed in a virtual env; it is using the version installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/` instead.

The configuration is for Django 1.4, but the Ubuntu installation you are using is running Django 1.3 or older instead.

You need to make sure you are using a virtualenv configured to run *without* site packages.

Comment: And to do this, you can use a code snippet like this in your `wsgi.py` file:
`activate_this = '/home/some_path/my_virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py'`
`execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))`

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Debian Wheezy), the python-django package installs "/usr/bin/django-admin".

Note the lack of ".py" on the name.  To run the django-admin from the virtualenv, either give the full path, or the name with .py on the end (django-admin.py).  Or both.

```
(TRIAL)bjb@bjb-pc:~/projects/python/django$ which django-admin
/usr/bin/django-admin
(TRIAL)bjb@bjb-pc:~/projects/python/django$ which django-admin.py
/usr/local/pythonenv/TRIAL/bin/django-admin.py
(TRIAL)bjb@bjb-pc:~/projects/python/django$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/pythonenv/TRIAL/bin:/home/bjb/bin:/usr/bin/mh:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/games:/opt/arm-2009q1/bin
```

So although the virtualenv bin directory has priority, since there is no "django-admin" file in bin there, the /usr/bin/django-admin gets picked up.

The point is that if your project got created using the wrong django-admin, then you will run into this error when you try to syncdb or do other things that use the executables in the virtualenv - as happened to me just now.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and solved with this command on terminal

```
user@computer:~$ source /your_django_directory/bin/activate
```

After you do that terminal turns out like this

```
(your_django_directory)user@computer:~$ source /your_django_directory/bin/activate
```

Than try syncdb again.